# How to uninstall Windows Script Host and install WSH 5.7

Tags: vbscript, windows

What I'm trying to achieve is to simply reinstall Windows Script Host.

However I can't uninstall WSH and when I try to run the Windows Script Host 5.7 installer I get an error of;

> Setup has detected that the Service Pack version of this system is newer than the update you are applying.
>
> There is no need to install this update.

I can confirm I'm running WSH 5.6.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP Service Pack 3 [installs WSH 5.7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952033/en-us). If you have SP3 installed on the machine in question already, you might consider re-installing it, as something apparently went wrong if you still can see it is 5.6 in the cscript version status line.

Comment: I can't uninstall SP3 as that is the initial OS installed, unless you know of a way to uninstall SP3

Comment: Just re-running the SP3 installer again should do the trick.